# Differential Equations in Milnor's Topology from the Differential Viewpoint

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

On page $23$ Milnor states:

> Let $\varphi$ : $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function which satisfies $$\begin{cases} \varphi(x) > 0, & {\rm for}\,\|x\| < 1 \\ \varphi(x) = 0, &{\rm for}\,\|x\| \geq 1\end{cases}$$
>   Given any fixed unit vector $c \in \mathbb{S} ^{n-1} $, consider the differential equations 
>   $$\frac{dx_i}{dt} = c_{i} \cdot \varphi(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n);  \hspace{10 mm} i = 1, \dots , n.$$
>   For any $ \hat x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ these equations have a unique solution $x = x(t)$, defined for all real numbers which satisfies the initial condition 
>   $$x(0)= \hat x.$$
>   We will use the notation $x(t) = F_{t}( \hat x)$ for this solution. Then clearly
>   **1)** $F_{t}$ is defined for all $t$ and $ \hat x $ and depends smoothly on $t$ and $ \hat x $,
>   **2)** $F_{0}( \hat x ) =  \hat x $,
>   **3)** $F_{s+t}( \hat x ) = F_{s} \circ F_{t}( \hat x )$.

**2)** is quite clear, however I don't understand why **1)** and **3)** are valid. Could anybody explain that?

Moreover on page $24$ Milnor states that

> clearly, with suitable choice of $c$ and $t$, the diffeomorphism $F_{t}$ will carry the origin to any desired point in the open unit ball.

Is that really 'clear'? Wouldn't it be necessary to show that $x(t) \rightarrow c$ when $t \rightarrow \infty $? If it is, how?

Thanks in advance.

Source:
http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/milnortop.pdf

Comment: Because $\phi$ has compact support and is smooth, $\phi'$ is bounded, hence uniformly Lipschitz. This gives existence and uniqueness. The system is time invariant, so time shifted solutions are also solutions.  The function $F$ gives the solution at time $t$ starting from $x$. I need to think if there is a quick answer to smoothness with respect to initial condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To answer your "Moreover" part:** The path $x(t)$ starts at $0$ and travels in a straight line in the direction $c$.  The limit of $x(t)$ as $t \to \infty$ must exist, because $x(t)$ is traveling in one direction on the straight line given by the vector $c$.    Let's call the limit $x_\infty$.  Now, you can imagine intuitively that the path must slow down as $t \to \infty$. By continuity of $\phi$ this should mean that $\phi$ is $0$ at $x_\infty$.  This means that $x_\infty$ must be at the boundary of the circle.

More rigorously, Suppose that $|x_\infty| < 1$.  There must be a sequence of times $t_n$ ($t_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$) such that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} |x'(t_n)| = 0.$$
(See edit 2 below.) Since (by the differential equation) $|x'(t_n)| = |\phi(x(t_n))||c|$ we have
$$0 = \lim_{n \to \infty} |x'(t_n)| = \lim_{n \to \infty}|\phi(x(t_n))||c| = \phi(x_\infty)|c|$$
and therefore $\phi(x_\infty) = 0$, so $x_\infty$ is on the boundary of the circle.

From this picture, you see that $x(t)$ sweeps out the whole line segment
$$\{rc : 0 < r < \frac{1}{|c|} \}$$

**Edit: let me answer your first part. (1)** The existence, uniqueness, and smoothness of the solution is a fact you may learn in an ODE course.  There are notes here:
math.ucsb.edu/~sideris/Math243-F09/notes-09-10.pdf
In particular, you want:

--Corollary 5.1.1 (Smooth dependence on initial conditions)

--Theorem 2.3.1 (Existence and Uniqueness)

It is a bit unfair to say 'clearly'.

**(3)** The third property essentially follows from uniqueness.  In words, the property says that "flowing for time $s+t$ is the same as flowing for time $t$, then flowing for time $s$."  To see this let $\hat x$ and $t$ be given.  Notice that
$$y(s) = F_{s+t}(\hat x)$$
and
$$z(s) = F_s \circ F_t(\hat x)$$
both satisfy the same equation and initial conditions:
$$\frac{dy(s)}{ds} = \phi(y(s))c \qquad y(0) = F_t(\hat x)$$
$$\frac{dz(s)}{ds} = \phi(z(s))c \qquad z(0) = F_t(\hat x)$$
so by uniqueness they must be the same.

**Edit 2: Clarification of the speed going to 0.**
Suppose there is no such sequence of times.  This would mean that $|x'(t)|$ stays large after some point in time.  Specifically, for some time $T$ and small $\delta$, for all $t > T$, we have $|x'(t)| > \delta$.  Thus the total distance traveled in the path $x(t)$:
$$\int_0^\infty |x'(t)|dt$$
is infinite.  That contradicts the fact that $x(t)$ starts at the origin, travels in the direction given by $c$, and does not go farther than distance 1 from the origin.

**Edit 3: Clarification clarification.**
Let's assume that $|c| = 1$, otherwise you just have to normalize some things.

Thinking about the path of the origin, we're looking at the ODE
$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = \varphi(x(t))c, \qquad x(0) = 0.$$
Since $x(t)$ is always a multiple of $c$ this is equivalent to the one dimensional ODE
$$\frac{dr(t)}{dt} = \psi(r(t)), \qquad r(0) = 0$$
where
$$x(t) = r(t)c, \qquad \psi(r) = \varphi(rc).$$
Since $\psi(r)\geq 0$, the solution $r(t)$ is increasing in time.  Furthermore $r(t)$ is bounded by $1$, because $\psi(r) = 0$ for $r\geq 1$.
Now,
$$r(T) = \int_0^T r'(t) dt$$
Since the left hand side is bounded as $T \to \infty$, and since the integrand is nonnegative, we have
$$\int_0^\infty r'(t) dt < \infty$$
which tells us $r'(t)$ must go to 0 as $t \to \infty$.  So,
$$0 = \lim_{t \to \infty}r'(t) = \lim_{t \to \infty}\psi(r(t)) = \psi(\lim_{t \to \infty}r(t))$$
which tells us $\lim_{t \to \infty}r(t)=1$.

Comment: Thank you, great explanations. Could you clarify why $\lim_{n \to \infty} |x'(t_n)| = 0$ in the first part?

Comment: I put an edit.  The answer is kind of based on intuition, but you can probably turn it into a calculation involving integrals.  The key thing for that would be the fact that $\left< x(t), c \right> =|c|^2 \int_0^t \phi(x(s)) ds $

Comment: I've thought about it, but I can't come up with anything useful. Could you give it a try to write a complete formal solution for the "moreover" part?

Comment: I added it again.  Hopefully putting it as a 1d ode makes it easier.